# Nopcommerce speed isuess

Tags: performance, nopcommerce

I have a nopcommerce 3.90 site, with 30000 articles and it running very slow. 
I followed the tips, but the problem still present:

https://www.nopcommerce.com/blog/56-common-tips-settings-recommendations-to-optimize-performance-in-nopcommerce.aspx

https://www.nop-templates.com/performance-optimizations-in-nopcommerce-33

https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/54986/nopcommerce-410-high-memory-usage-and-how-weve-handled-it.aspx

I'm looking for some suggestions or someone to help me to speed it up.

Comment: articles? do you mean products?

Comment: Yes i wanted to say products

Comment: 30K is not much, could you please enable memory profiler and check which method takes log time?

Comment: Thank you reply, you could explain what does you mean for "enable memory profiler".

Comment: Go to advance settings and search for "profiler" and enable it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHctQ.png

Comment: This will enable mini-profiler at front side, where you can find detail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTy3P.png

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't know this feature. I'm checking which method takes log time

Comment: Well, you have taken kinda more time than your website running :D

Comment: Than you Div
https://imgur.com/a/VIbm6Vg
This is an example, but is all site too slow.
If i insert more then 20 product in cart, order take 3 minutes to complete task.

Comment: I can see 7Spikes plugins, disabled them all, and share the result.

Answer (score 0):

to speed up your nopcommerce 3.9 website you have to check major things in three layers.
A- code
B- network
C- resource and server
at first I have to mention that I have been lunched a nopcommerce 3.6 project in high traffic environment that reached 6k concurrent users (live user or real-time user).

A - code:
in nop 3.9, there are some performance issues that can be resolve easily:

1- try to return your default language whenever it calls for user language.
2- try return your default store whenever it calls for current store.
3- refactor your global.asax file to avoid multiple calls for same values to database.
4- use output cache to cache your service layer for queries that need.
5- (optional) try to keep your media files to another server and read them over url
6- (optional) try to use multiple web servers with minimum resource instead of one high resource server as web application servers.

B - Network
1- use CDN (cloudflare is good option).
2- try to cache you static files in network layer instead of webserver layer.
3- separate your db server and application server but put them in a same machine.

C - Resource and Service
1- boost your IIS webserver performance (there are thousand of resources available on internet for this).
2- make your windows server use CPU for IIS by disabling not necessary apps that are taking your cpu.
3- having more cores of cpu can help you.
4- (optional) use multiple servers as i said before and use loadbalancing methods like round robin to share request over all your servers (don't forget to use same machine key in this case).

as there are multiple ways to boost your nop3.9 website performance, I can help you with detailed information of each one but as I said, there thousand of information about each step on internet.